# Share Sitecore content to Native Mobile Apps (IOS swift and Android java)

Tags: personalization, jss, sitecore-services-client, item-web-api, mobile

If we wanted to provide data (get/set operations on content tree, analytics, personalization, tracking data) from Sitecore 9 to native mobile apps (not based on Sitecore Mobile SDK and Xamarin but created using IOS swift and Android java) , in this case Sitecore 9 item web service and XConnect can be utilized or XConnect with JSS can be utilized?

As per inputs from  JSS slack channel Layout service can helpful but:

> If user accessing the different-2 pages from mobile and in one of the page, one rendering having personalization based on Goal or User persona (Profile card) then Layout service will return personalized content for that page?
>
> How to push tracking data for personalization ( which cookies value needs to be set from app) from native mobile app?

Please let me know, what are the ways or recommended approach to share data (content, analytics, personalization, tracking) from Sitecore 9 to native mobile apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add more to Artsem's answer and to answer the additional questions that were not answered.

> If we wanted to provide data (get/set operations on content tree,
>   analytics, personalization, tracking data) from Sitecore 9 to native
>   mobile apps ... , in this case Sitecore 9 item web service and
>   XConnect can be utilized or XConnect with JSS can be utilized?

Considering the wide range of requirements, *both* [the Item Service (Sitecore Service Client)](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/sitecore-services-client.html) and [the Layout Service](https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/fundamentals/services/layout-service) have to be used.
The Item Service provides a RESTful API to create and retrieve items, though it does not support personalization and tracking. Therefore, the Layout Service has to be used to retrieve personalized content.

Using xConnect for tracking/ submitting interaction data from native mobile apps to Sitecore might not be an ideal scenario, as xConnect can  receive data only from trusted clients with the correct client certificates. Therefore, if you use Sitecore 9.1 or later, it is advantageous to use Sitecore Universal Tracker. For more information and examples on how it can be done for native mobile apps, you can read [this blog post](https://staticreadonly.com/2019/05/18/approaches-for-writing-interaction-data-from-native-mobile-apps-to-sitecore-with-examples-for-android-kotlin/).
And if it is an earlier version of Sitecore, then a trusted intermediary application have to be created that [receives interaction data from mobile apps and submits it to xConnect](https://staticreadonly.com/2019/06/08/an-alternative-approach-for-sending-interaction-data-from-native-mobile-apps-to-sitecore/).

Considering that cookie-based tracking is not available in the context  of native mobile apps, the Layout Service will not know what contact is it to be able to apply contact-related personalization. One of the approaches for how to accomplish this in the context of native mobile applications:

- Create an API endpoint that is aware of HttpContext and Sitecore, accepts a contact identifier (e.g. username/email address) and identifies the contact.
- A native mobile application will send a contact identifier to the endpoint by using an HTTP client and with the response SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE cookie is returned.
- A mobile app will pass the analytics cookie with every request to the Layout Service endpoint.

> not based on Sitecore Mobile SDK and Xamarin but created using IOS
>   swift and Android java

For Android, cookie management can be handled with these HTTP clients:

- [khttp](https://khttp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#cookies);
- [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) by using [CookieJar](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-cookie-jar/) or an [interceptor](https://gist.github.com/tsuharesu/cbfd8f02d46498b01f1b);
- [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection) by using [CookieManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CookieManager.html);

And for iOS(Swift) there are also a few options, one of them involves HTTPCookieStorage, for more details you can check [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464785/swift-how-to-remember-cookies-for-further-http-requests).

> If user accessing the different-2 pages from mobile and in one of the
>   page, one rendering having personalization based on Goal or User
>   persona (Profile card) then Layout service will return personalized
>   content for that page?

This personalization rule (based on profile card) will work only if the analytics cookie is sent from the native mobile app together with the request to the Layout Service. I've described above how it can be accomplished.

The following example is for Android, using khttp HTTP client, though you might want to implement more sophisticated cookie management mechanism.

Requesting the cookie from our identification API endpoint:

```
val queryStr = mapOf("identifier" to "username")
val result = get("https://yourdomain/identify", params=queryStr)

//accessing the response cookies
result.cookies["SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE"]

// "b0760a00d4cc4503a6169a1aa9cfb71a|True" -
// a device GUID/ a tracker identifier
```

And then sending the request to the Layout Service together with the analytics cookie:

```
val queryStr = mapOf("item" to "[path]",
                  "sc_lang" to "[language]",
                  "sc_apikey" to "[key]",
                  "tracking" to "[true]")

val url = "http://yourdomain/sitecore/api/layout/render/[config]"

val cookies = mapOf("SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE" to cookieValue)

//sending the analytics cookie together with request to the Layout Service
val result = get(url, cookies=cookies, params=queryStr)
```

The approach for personalization and tracking for the native mobile apps can be visualized with the following figure:

[image]

For more details and examples you can read [this blog post](https://staticreadonly.com/2019/07/06/enabling-contact-related-personalization-when-retrieving-sitecore-content-for-native-mobile-apps/), which is a part of blog post series on this subject.

Comment: Thanks @sergey-krivchenko, This is what exactly we have implemented except Universal Tracker. Here is one query, If Layout Service is capable enough to write interaction data from native mobile apps to Sitecore using JSS Tracker than why we need to use Sitecore Universal Tracker for the mobile apps?

Answer (score 6):

In my point of view, JSS is pretty suite for your requirements. I've implemented something like you want with Xamarin. But I think it doesn't matter with which technology to do that because I didn't use any Xamarin Sitecore specific frameworks or tools. I only send simple HTTP requests to LayoutService.

> If user accessing the different-2 pages from mobile and in one of the page, one rendering having personalization based on Goal or User persona (Profile card) then Layout service will return personalized content for that page?

Yes, Layout Service returns the data with applied personalization rules.

> How to push tracking data for personalization ( which cookies value needs to be set from app) from native mobile app?

Actually there are a few things that you need to take into account:

- You need to pass "tracking=true" parameter for getting personalized results (`{YOUR_DOMAIN}/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_lang=en&tracking=true&sc_apikey={F3A7F3C9-0D0D-4F57-8D8A-5BFCAA4C349B}`)
- You need to identify user if you want to get personalized results otherwise you will receive a content as for anonymous user

I added a web service with the following method to identify contact:

```
public JsonResult Identify(string email)
    {
        if (email == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(email));

        Tracker.Current.Session.IdentifyAs("identification-source-name", email);

        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Then I send a request to this method with contact identificator (email in my case) and it returns me `SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE` cookie. You need to pass this cookie with all requests to JSS. It allows you to retrieve personalized content for your contact.

The following method I've used for forgetting user in case I need to change context contact:

```
public JsonResult ForgetCurrentContact()
    {
        if (Tracker.Current != null)
        {
            Tracker.Current.EndVisit(true);
        }

        HttpContext.Session.Abandon();

        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Great answer! Just a quick note that the `tracking` parameter is `true` by default for Layout Service requests and should only need to be passed if you want to set tracking to `false`.

Comment: I should also mention that you don't have to use the `jss` configuration for Layout Service. If the JSS JSON format doesn't suit your needs, you can create your own "named configuration" for Layout Service that will allow you to shape the JSON to align with your app. For instance, SXA has its own Layout Service named configuration. More info on named configurations can be found here: https://jss.sitecore.net/#/layout-service?id=layout-service-configuration

Comment: @AdamWeber Thank you Adam for your notes! Actually, JSS in general and the LayoutService in particular were created as tools for achieving headless principle and it is the most matching to be used for integration between Sitecoore and any native mobile app languages. It is really flexible and probably each thing can be customized. Powerful technology! Really recommended.

Comment: I agree! I'm on the team that's building JSS :)

Comment: I know :) I was in the round table session with you at SUGCON :)

Comment: Adam and Artsem Thanks for your valuable inputs. I will try creating POC on this and will share the findings.

Comment: Is it help you? Does you PoC work?

Comment: @AmitKumar any progress on POC? do you want to share the details?

Comment: I created the poc to access the content into html JavaScript application with personalization and it was working fine, so thought of using the same approach in mobile app.

Comment: @ArtsemPrashkovich - on the same topic, how would you track multivariate testing using the layout service?

Comment: You have to assign presentation to Sitecore item then you can use A/B testing.

Comment: @VarunNehra For multivariate testing, you have to utilize the Sitecore Instance and verify the Engagement values using A/B testing.

Comment: @AshishBansal: If any page is secure page in your content tree, i.e. if any logic implemented that after authentication (virtual login) only user can access the content otherwise redirect to login page. In this case, if you try to access content from other channel without loggin-in then from Layout Service you will get login page content.

Comment: @AshishBansal : Have you implemented personalization using SITECORE JSS for logged-in user?

Comment: @ArtsemPrashkovich i have implemented above suggestions but logged-in user personalization showing after page refresh only. Added the details at https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18616/logged-in-user-personalization-including-virtual-user-and-sitecore-contact-using